# Recover an id from a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to recover the id of the displayed element of my ViewFlipper, something like "R.id.xxx" who's inside an Integer list[], I've tried something found on stackoverflow :

```
int Id=randImage();
ViewFlipper.setImageResource(Id);
```

but randImage() does not exist, an I need to recover the "xxx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that R.id.your_view_flipper is your `ViewFlipper` that has been defined in the XML layout file of your current `Activity`:

```
ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.your_view_flipper);
View currentView = viewFlipper.getCurrentView();
int id = currentView.getId();
```

`id` is what you are looking for.

Comment: You cannot recover the id in the form 'R.id.xxx'. This is because when you build the project Eclipse converts all the resources to int values. If you look at the R.Java in the 'gen' folder you will see the int values for each id. You can do a comparison though like: if (id == R.id.xxx) //Do something

Comment: The problem is that I have 6 lists of 10 elements, I need to test the id "xxx" to know what I have to display (Under the ViewFlipper I have to display 1 to 3 icons, and it depends on the image displayed).

Comment: The value behind R.id.xxx an integer, which is an id of a particular view. This is exactly the same integer which View.getId() returns.

Comment: Paul, your command only return an id=-1 (for every slide), I need to get "xxx" to use ".split("_")", in order to display some buttons.

Comment: So, I've found a solution to get the name of my displayed element, I travel an arraylist and I use this : getResources().getResourceEntryName(aray_list1.get(i));